# how do I add a RCP project to eclipse menu?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rcp

I have an eclipse RCP application (already built). I need to integrate it with eclipse UI itself. What I mean is -- I want to add a menu option in eclipse User Interface and a command in the menu which when clicked runs the application. 
It is similar to find and replace option in the eclipse menu

Any idea how this can be done?

I also want the application to be bundled with eclipse

Comment: So you write an Eclipse plugin which is installed in Eclipse and adds the menu item to run the app. What part of this is a problem?

Comment: the menu item needs to be added to the eclipse menu itself not the applcation's menu bar

Comment: Yes so you write a plugin which is installed in Eclipse not your RCP.

Comment: I mean every time eclipse is opened -- that menu option should appear along with other usual menu options like file, edit , navigate etc

Comment: sorry i am new to this... can you please explain how to write a plugin that would do this when installed or any link that would help me?

Answer (score 0):

Write a plugin that you install in to Eclipse (rather than your RCP).

The plugin can use the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point to add to the `File` menu. For example:

```xml
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:file?after=open.ext">
     <command
           commandId="my.command.id"
           id="my.menu.id"
           style="push">
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
```

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point to define the command

```xml
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <command
        id="my.commnd.id"
        description="Description text"
        name="Name">
  </command>
```

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` extension point to define a handler for the command

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler
        class="package.CommandHandler"
        commandId="my.command.id">
  </handler>
```

The handler contains the code to run your RCP:

```java
public class CommandHandler extends AbstractHandler
{
  public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException
  {
    // TODO launch your RCP

    return null;
  }
}
```